# POSTMAN - Issue with resolving of variables

Tags: postman

I have two environmental variables set.

1] firstName = "abc"

2] firstNameUpdate = "{{firstName}}Update"

when I say -

> console.log(postman.getEnvironmentVariable("firstNameUpdated"));

I am getting --> **{{firstName}}Update** instead of **abcUpdat**e in the console log.

which fails my below code

```
tests["Success"] = jsonData.data.firstName === postman.getEnvironmentVariable("firstNameUpdated");
```

Problem is postman.getEnvironmentVariable() returns the value of the variable, but it does not resolve the variable. How to achieve it?

I don't want to use regular expression here, want to achieve it from Postman itself. Any help guys?

Other details :

Postman for Chrome

Version 5.0.2

win / x86-64

Chrome 59.0.3071.115

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible for postman to resolve your environment variable like this. If it is a matter of building your variable dynamically you may proceed like this in your "tests" tab:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("firstname","abc");
var name_update = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("firstname")+"update";
console.log(name_update); // you can see your second env var name
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("firstnameupdate",name_update);
// you can check your env var content:
var check_env = postman.getEnvironmentVariable("firstnameupdate");
console.log(check_env); // this should give you abcupdate
```

hope this helps

Alexandre

Comment: Thanks Alex, your solution worked and let me know in future if you find any way to resolve a variable using postman.

Comment: You're welcome :) . You may set this subject as resolved (tick mark, under the votes) so the community can see that the answer is efficient.

Comment: I ticked your answer.. hope I made this question as resolved. :)